# How to change order of pages when using \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}?

Tags: printing, pgfpages

I have a 100 pages text file in Latex, using A5 paper landscape, memoir template.
Now I want to print it on A4 paper (two A5 per side).
To do it, I use the command bellow:

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper]
```

The command works fine, and fits page 1(A5) and 2(A5) on the A4 front and page 3(A5) and 4(A5) in the A4 page cover.
I need to change the order: I want the A4 front page with pages 1 and 3 (A5 odd pages), and the A4 cover with pages 2 and 4 (a5 even pages).
How can I do it?

Here is the Code Example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,landscape]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper]
\begin
\lipsum[1-6]
\end
```

The result is a two page document:

[image]

I need a two page document, but I need the odd A5 pages in a page, and the even A5 pages in other page:

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome! Code for a small document will make it more likely you'll get help than providing a mere code fragment. Have you checked the manual? I'd use `pdfpages` for this, which makes this kind of manipulation easy. (Or post-process the document.)

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: As I say, `pdfpages` or a post-processing option are your best bets, I think. With `pdfpages`, you use two `.tex` files and then it is straightforward.